# Изменить значение ключа

Tags: swift, словари

Я хочу сделать так: когда нажимаешь на картинку в словарь imagesName записывается его ключ как название картинки и его значение сколько раз пользователь нажал clickCount. Как сделать чтобы для каждого ключа менялось его значение на +1?

Код:

```
//My Dictionary
var imageNames: [String: Int] = [:]

//The name of my images
descriptionOneLabel.text 
descriptionTwoLabel.text

//Logic when tapped 
var clickCount = 0

imageNames[descriptionOneLabel.text!] = clickCount + 1 
imageNames[descriptionTwoLabel.text!] = clickCount + 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно получать значение ключа и увеличивать его на единицу, вот так:

```
imageNames[descriptionOneLabel.text!] = (imageNames[descriptionOneLabel.text!] ?? 0) + 1
```

Comment: Благодарю, это решение мне помогло.

Comment: Вместо `?? 0` можно `,default: 0]` записать